# Is possible to configure all setup one drive azzure in asp.net application

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, onedrive

I'v chalange to build applicatiin using asp.net core integrated with azure AD and One Drive...i can get acces one drive/office 365 with sdk..but, for setting priviledge and all configuration must be in portal azure for user Azure on AD(active directory)..it posible to setup permission and all configuration on my website application, it is possible or not...so, i can manage from my application not from azure portal again...my question is possible or not..
I was trying looking for on website microsoft, but I not found the information for my case,.....thanks advance..please share me link

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD V2.0 allows an app to request permissions dynamically through the `scope` parameter gives developers full control over your user's experience.

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=xxxxxxe&scope=https://graph.windows.net/directory.read%20https://graph.windows.net/directory.write
```

The `scope` parameter indicates which resource and permissions the app is requesting authorization. If the permissions need admin consent , it's better to set those permissions for apps in the app registration portal if you need an admin to give consent on behalf of the entire organization. This reduces the cycles required by the organization admin to set up the application.

You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#incremental-and-dynamic-consent) and the code samples : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2